# injecting many files with three specific at bottom

Tags: gulp, src, inject

I need to inject all the files,and reinject the last three, all.css, foo.css and app.min.js so they are injected last.
Injecting task :

```
return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['temp/**/*.css','!temp/**/all.css','!temp/**/foo.css','./temp/**/*.js','!temp/**/app.min.js'], {read: false}), {ignorePath: 'temp'} ))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['temp/**/all.css','temp/**/foo.css,'temp/**/app.min.js'], {read: false}), {ignorePath: 'temp'} ))    
        .pipe(gulp.dest('temp'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
}
```

The way that i made it, it just overrides my first injection and injects only the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject a single stream. That means you need to add the files from your second stream to the end of the first stream. The [`gulp-add-src`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src) package let's you do that:

```
var addSrc = require('gulp-add-src');

var files = gulp.src(['temp/**/*.css','!temp/**/all.css','!temp/**/foo.css','./temp/**/*.js','!temp/**/app.min.js'], {read: false})
 .pipe(addSrc.append(['temp/**/all.css','temp/**/foo.css','temp/**/app.min.js'], {read: false}));

return gulp.src('src/index.html')
  .pipe(inject(files, {ignorePath: 'temp'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('temp'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
```