# How to do .pipe inject and transform twice without replacing the previous inject?

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-inject

```
     var isA=true;
     var isB=true;   

     var ASources = gulp.src([srcFolder + '/app/A/'+ client + '.js'], {read: false});
     var BSources = gulp.src([srcFolder + '/app/B/'+ client + '.js'], {read: false});

     var transformPathA = {
                  transform: function (filepath) {
                      return '<script type="text/javascript" src="${requestScope.contextRoot}/' + FolderName + '/A.js"></script>';

                  }
            }

     var transformPathB = {
                      transform: function (filepath) {
                          return '<script type="text/javascript" src="${requestScope.contextRoot}/' + FolderName + '/BSources.js"></script>';
                          // Use the default transform as fallback: 
                          //return inject.transform.apply(inject.transform, arguments);
                      }
                }

     return gulp.src ( [srcFolder + '/app/*.jsp', srcFolder + '/app/*.jsp'] ) 
            .pipe(gulpif(isA, inject(ASources, transformPathA)))
            .pipe(gulpif(isB, inject(BSources, transformPathB)))

    } );
```

In this

```
.pipe(gulpif(isA, inject(ASources, transformPathA)))
.pipe(gulpif(isB, inject(BSources, transformPathB)))
```

If i do the second .pipe inject , it is replacing the first one.

In home.jsp

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject --> if i add this, only the last file is getting placed here.
```

I'm very new to this gulp tasks. If anyone can help , it would be great.Thanks in advance.

How to do this pipe inject of two files simultaneously? These two files should appear in my home.jsp inbetween those

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [injecting many files with three specific at bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338626/injecting-many-files-with-three-specific-at-bottom)

Comment: @SvenSchoenung  No i need to do transform path also.This is diferent.